# MS Word eps image insert broken

Tags: ms-word, eps

Insert of eps images in ms word 365 worked until now.

Since two weeks insert of eps is broken. After insert of a eps images I see only an empty frame.

See the reason and a solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

Microsoft included a security feature in one if the latest security updates (968095 MS10-105):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2479871/security-settings-for-graphic-filters-for-microsoft-office-365

To re-enable the import of eps images:

Open regedit.exe:

Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Common\

Add the keys manually: Security\AllowLists\GraphicsFilterImport

Add the values:

AllowListEnabled    REG_DWORD   0x00000001 (1)

EPSIMP32.FLT    REG_SZ  2012.1600.4309.1000

[image: RegEdit]

In my installation insert of eps images in MS Word was possible again.

Comment: I also have this problem. Note that there are warnings about security in the link you provided. But you answered my lingering question: The keys Security\AllowLists\GraphicsFilterImport did not appear in my system so I have had to add them.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.
Is there any method to allow all graphics?

Comment: This solution used to work, but MS has disabled EPS support permanently in April 2018, with no way for the user to re-enable it. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/support-for-eps-images-has-been-turned-off-in-office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840